# Beautiful Soup returning XX instead of actual values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to Webscrape a website using requests and beautiful soup.

But I am getting 'XXX' instead of the text within the tags.

code:

```py
url = 'https://www.discover.com/student-loans/'

req = opener.open(url)
data = req.read().decode('utf8')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
rate_element = soup.find('div',class_='variableRate')
if rate_element :
        rate_Fixed = rate_element.get_text().strip()
        print("Interest rates:",rate_Fixed)
else:
        print('rate not found')
```

Comment: In the title you say XX but in the body of the question XXX. In tçthe code you posted opener is undefined

Comment: Looks like the page uses JavaScript to write the values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The reason you see these X values is because they are placeholder values that the other site is using before the values are filled in with JavaScript. BeautifulSoup **cannot run JavaScript or figure out what effect it will have on the page**. Please see the linked duplicate to understand this very common problem. To help with future questions, please read [mre] and [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379), and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.